# How to reimplement accidents under Veins?

Tags: omnet++

I want to know how accidents are implemented under Veins 2.0 & in general (with the use of TraciMobility module) ? 
I checked the last code version and seems that the mecanism behind accidents simulations is the same.

What i noted, responsible code is the following:

```
//in TraCIMobility::initialize() method

if (accidentCount > 0) {
        simtime_t accidentStart = par("accidentStart");
        startAccidentMsg = new cMessage("scheduledAccident");
        stopAccidentMsg = new cMessage("scheduledAccidentResolved");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentStart, startAccidentMsg);
}


//in TraCIMobility::handleSelfMsg() method

if (msg == startAccidentMsg) {
        commandSetSpeed(0);
        simtime_t accidentDuration = par("accidentDuration");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentDuration, stopAccidentMsg);
        accidentCount--;
}
```

So, if i understand correctly, this mecanism set only the current speed of vehicle to 0 but don't order it to stop moving and staying at the current position ?!

Suppose that i want to simulate accident by ordering vehicles to directly stop at their current positions ? how can i achieve it ? by using the stop Traci command ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

The implementation of accidents under Veins 2.0 (i guess that is the same for upper version) is as i sayed previously, by setting speed to 0 (with the use of Traci command/variable : [Change Vehicle State(0xc4) /speed (0x40)](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State)).

If someone want to implement accidents in a differents manners, for exemple by stopping a car at position X under road Y, you have to reimplement accident by using Traci command/variable: Change Vehicle State(0xc4) /stop (0x12), this command takes as arguments position X and road Y.

Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

Setting a vehicle's speed via [Command 0xc4 0x40](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State) takes effect immediately and remains in effect until set to a different speed or reset (by passing a value of -1).

You can find more details in the SUMO documentation of its TraCI API.

Comment: but it doesn't stop the car, because the car need to decelerate in order to stop, so when using this command, the car starts breaking, until it halts

Comment: You might need to use command 0xb3 (speed mode) to disregard maximum deceleration.

Comment: i tried to use accidents as they are implemented under Veins, which is resumed in setting speed to 0, anyway Vehicle continue its trajectory for 20-30m which is the distance needed to halt the car. So in order to correct it i implemented accidents with the use of command stop veh